# Why is this angular-cli Jasmine test passing?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli

I've run into a very interesting problem while writing tests for my Angular 2 services. I run tests under the >ng test command of angular-cli, so they are Jasmine tests run by Karma.

Here is my test:

```
it('should get path from the server once and save it to the service', inject([LookupService, XHRBackend], (_service, _mockBackend) => {
    let responseOptions = new ResponseOptions({ body: JSON.stringify({ path: 'http://example.com/api/' }) });

    var lastConnection;
    _mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
        lastConnection = connection;
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(responseOptions));
    });

    _service.getPath()
        .then((firstResponse) => {
            _service.getPath()
                .then((secondResponse) => {
                    expect(2).toBe(1);
                });
        });
}));
```

Notice that I call the asynchronous _service.getPath() twice; the idea here is that on the first call, it retrieves the relevant data from the server and stores it in the service, so that on the second call no server request is made. I noticed, however, that any expect statements within the second lambda do not seem to register with the test runner. That is, even if the expect fails, the test itself does not fail.

Via debugging, I know that the code in that block is executing, and I know that even in my real test (which is a bit more complex than expecting 2 to be 1) I am getting two unequal numbers.

Now here's the really weird part: the false positive only appears for the final test in the file. So if I add a dummy test below this one, like so:

```
it('should get path from the server once and save it to the service', inject([LookupService, XHRBackend], (_service, _mockBackend) => {
    let responseOptions = new ResponseOptions({ body: JSON.stringify({ path: 'http://example.com/api/' }) });

    var lastConnection;
    _mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
        lastConnection = connection;
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(responseOptions));
    });

    _service.getPath()
        .then((firstResponse) => {
            _service.getPath()
                .then((secondResponse) => {
                    expect(2).toBe(1);
                });
        });
}));

it('should really work without this', inject([LookupService, XHRBackend], (_service, _mockBackend) => {

}));
```

Then the test that was previously passing fails, as it should.

I can only imagine that this is some sort of async issue, but I believe my promises are executing correctly, and I am using Angular 2's MockBackend to mock HTTP calls, which is actually synchronous. What has me stumped is why the presence of another test would affect the one above it, when each test has the service and mock backend injected individually. Shouldn't each test run in isolation?

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: Because the test isn't marked as asynchronous? Wrap it with `async` or `fakeAsync`.

Comment: The test is not actually asynchronous, though, since MockBackend behaves synchronously. Do I need to mark it async because it uses promises?

Comment: Also, fakeAsync doesn't work with XHR.

Comment: @estus Despite my skepticism, wrapping my tests in `async` seems to have done the trick! I suppose it has to do with handling of promises?

Comment: No, fakeAsync does, because you use MockBackend and don't do real XHR in unit tests. Yes, that's because of promises. Promises are asynchronous. You can either use async workflow suggested by Jasmine (done param) or use Angular async/fakeAsync helpers.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I have been working from this article: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-testing-guide-a485b6cb1ef0 which blurs the lines between its XHR and MockBackend examples somewhat. It also states that async isn't necessary with MockBackend, which I suppose is true, but does not use promises in its examples. Thanks for your help. Feel free to officially answer the question if you'd like the credit!